# Angular2 Router not navigation on login

Tags: angular

I am confused as to why the router isn't navigation to the requested route after a successful login.  The console output does show that the user should be sent to the last URL I clicked that the AuthGuard rejected, but the router.navigate line in my subscribe doesn't seem to do doing this navigation.

```
onLogin() {
    if (this.formCredentials.valid) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.auth.login(this.formCredentials.value.username, this.formCredentials.value.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.access_token);
              localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh_token);
              this.auth.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
              console.log(this.auth.lastUrl);
              this.router.navigate([this.auth.lastUrl]);
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
              var err = error.json();
              localStorage.removeItem('auth_error');
              localStorage.setItem('auth_error', JSON.stringify(err));
              this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
              this.isLoading = false;
            },
            () => {
              this.isLoading = false;
            }
          );
    }
  }
```

Comment: does this.auth.lastUrl contain a valid route relative to the navigation? (i.e. not the full url...)

Comment: what is the console.log output of `this.auth.lastUrl`

Comment: I actually was just pointed to the issue by a coworker:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13530

Comment: @Bean0341 The console output is:  /audiences

Comment: according to my plunker, as long as you are getting back a `/whatever` route then there shouldnt be an issue. see src/home.ts in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/rsAt3JavBIkfMsKB6LH7?p=preview

Comment: @Bean0341 It seems that it's when you have the AuthGuard in the mix, is when the issue starts to occur.  The pull request summarizes the issue as:

Description:
The initial navigation is canceled by guard which returns false, but Router.navigated is set to true anyway.
Router initialized with the url equals to /, so when the second navigation occurs (this.router.navigate(['/'])), router compares / and /, and cancels navigation, because it's not allowed to navigate to the same url again.
I think we should set Router.navigated to true only after the first successful navigation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a known issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13929